# Limit size for custom home directory on a network

Tags: active-directory, centos7, pam

I have configured Centos 7.5 server to use windows active directory information using **sssd**. Also set a custom **/home** path on a network path for all AD users using pam. All AD users are now able to login successfully and on-the-fly **/home** is getting created using the following edit.

```
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /<server_path>/home/%u
```

Now all that is left, is to limit size for the newly created home automatically for all users. I want to limit the size of /home for all AD users to **500 MB**.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this help:
https://superuser.com/questions/1268730/setting-disk-quotas-with-active-directory
Or if you have these AD on linux, just create quota for users:
https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-disk-quotas-assigning-user.html

Comment: Hi parasit,  Thanks for replying. I checked out both the links. The first has to do more with limiting size with AD which isn't dynamic and also can't take the custom /home path for all individual users.  The second link tells how to configure quotas through edquota which is although for linux for still isn't dynamic.  Is there a simpler way like may editing a pam config...   for eg: **fallback_homedir_size = 500MB**

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on `Server Fault`.